# ASP Dot Net : How to repeat HTML parts with minor differences on a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's a really simple problem.

I've got HTML code like this :

```
<div>
 <img src="image1.jpg" alt="test1" />
</div>
<div>
 <img src="image2.jpg" alt="test2" />
</div>
<div>
 <img src="image3.jpg" alt="test3" />
</div>
```

etc...

The data is comming from a DB (image name, alt text).

In JAVA, I would do something like :

save the info in array in the back end.

For the presentation I would loop through it with JSTL :

```
<c:foeach items="${data}" var="${item}>
<div>
 <img src="${item.image}" alt="${item.alt}" />
</div>
</c:foreach>
```

What's the best practice in **ASP.net** I just don't want to create a string with HTML code in it in the "code behind", it's ugly IMO.

Comment: Your HTML did not show up. You might want to re-add it and make sure it's visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this without being able to see your code:

Check out the ASP:Repeater control. Between that and binding your data (with your variances) to it, it may do what you want.

[Link 1](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control)
[Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)

<Edit:>
Okay, now that I see your code, I can help you better. I'd definitely use a repeater for this. I would do it like this in the ASPX file (I may have some errors in this):

```
<ASP:Repeater id="MyRepeater" runat="server">
  <div>
    <img src="<%# Eval("Filename")>" alt="<$# Eval("AltText")>" />
  </div>
</ASP:Repeater>
```

Then in your C# you could have:

```
List<ObjectWithFilenameAndAltText> foo = GoGetTheseObjects();
MyRepeater.DataSource = foo;
MyRepeater.DataBind();
```

I may have some errors in this but I hope this gets you moving in the right direction. If you don't have a dedicated object for your images, you could simply use a Dictionary or List> and use "Key" and "Value" in your ASPX code.

Comment: thanks. But I lied a little, the data is not 100% from the DB, would it still work?

Comment: You don't need DataSets or DataTables to use a repeater. You can bind them against .NET collections as well

Comment: I just updated my answer with more details for you to get your started. You can use anything that's IEnumerable among many other things.

Comment: Just for the record, your html template for the `asp:Repeater` should go inside a `<ItemTemplate>` section.

Answer (score 2):

This is the equivalent markup for the .ASPX file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="imageList" Runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <img 
                src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageSrc") %>" 
                alt="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Alt") %>" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the code-behind, you should set the imageList.DataSource property and call imageList.DataBind().

Comment: Or you can use a ListItem and the Attribute bag using e.g. `<%# ((ListItem)Container.DataItem).Attributes["MyDate"]%>`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the `Repeater` control.

For your example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="yourRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Image ID="yourImage" runat="server"
                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'
                ToolTip='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
List<MockData> lst = new List<MockData>();
lst.Add(new MockData() { Name = "Picture 1", Url = "pic1.jpg" });
lst.Add(new MockData() { Name = "Picture 2", Url = "pic2.jpg" });
lst.Add(new MockData() { Name = "Picture 3", Url = "pic3.jpg" });
yourRepeater.DataSource = lst;
yourRepeater.DataBind();
```