# How can I repeat a <tr> in c# to make a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wanna make a list using

This is my code on listOfPeople.aspx:

```
<table id="listOfPeople" runat="server">
<tr id="rowOfPerson" runat="server">
 <td id="person" runat="server">name of a person</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to repeat the  to make a list of people via c#:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Charles Bell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Jason Mc Allister</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Mathew Anderson</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can see "rowOfPerson" on listOfPerson.aspx.cs but I dont know how to create new rows. Thanks.

Comment: are you asking for someone to write the C# code to do this?

Comment: There are lots of ways.  Are you using WebForms or MVC?  With the latter it's a simple loop in the view code.  With the former maybe something like a `Repeater` would be your best bet.

Comment: Google "aspx repeat", get http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp as the third hit...

Comment: Depends if you just want to output it any way thats possible or if you want to do it vaguely correctly :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP Dot Net : How to repeat HTML parts with minor differences on a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479195/asp-dot-net-how-to-repeat-html-parts-with-minor-differences-on-a-page)

Comment: Use asp:Repeater, bind your name in ItemTemplate, the table open tag in the header template and the table closing tag in footer template.

Comment: Thanks to all. I use an aspRepeater. I didnt know it.

Comment: reconsider your markup if its a single column table. If this is the case an unordered list `<ul>` with list items `<li>` would be the more correct element to use.

Comment: `<table>`'s are for tabular data. `<ul>` `<ol>` are for Lists. Use HTML elements for their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the table html in the aspx. 
In your aspx.cs, write the entire table (including all the rows you want) so that it get rendered dynamically based on whatever your data source is.
This is just one of many ways, but i believe it is the simplest and quickest way for you to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways...

Put this html in repeater control and assign the datasaource to it

```
<tr id="rowOfPerson" runat="server">
 <td id="person" runat="server">name of a person</td>
</tr>
```

Use anyother ways like add table with runat server attribute... loop through data in code and add tr for that table for your data...